# issue with java.length or possibly my entire program

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I get an error in my code for line 56. I'm trying to make a program that will convert sentences into pig Latin.

Can anyone understand why this code isn't running? It was made in ready to program.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class PigLatin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel lblInput, lblOutput;
    TextField txtInput, txtOutput;
    Button btnReverse, btnClear;
    String Broken;

    Container frame;

    public PigLatin() {
        frame = getContentPane();

        setTitle("PigLatin"); // Set the frame's name

        lblInput = new JLabel("Enter a phrase");
        lblOutput = new JLabel("Pig Latinified");
        txtInput = new TextField(50);
        txtOutput = new TextField(50);

        btnReverse = new Button("Reverse String");
        btnClear = new Button("Clear");

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));

        frame.add(lblInput);
        frame.add(txtInput);
        frame.add(lblOutput);
        frame.add(txtOutput);
        frame.add(btnReverse);
        frame.add(btnClear);

        btnReverse.addActionListener(this);
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);

        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);

    } // Constructor


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String DNC = "does not compute";

        Broken = txtInput.getText();

        String Inp[] = Broken.split(" ");
        int N;

        for (int i = 0; i < Inp[i].length(); i++) {
            N = i;

            char Q = Inp[N].charAt(0);
            char Vowel = Inp[N].charAt(1);
            if (Q == 'a' || Q == 'e' || Q == 'i' || Q == 'o' || Q == 'u') {
                txtOutput.setText("" + Inp[N] + "way");
            } else if (Q == 'q' && Vowel == 'u') {
                String quay = Inp[N];
                quay = quay.replaceAll("q", "");
                quay = quay.replaceAll("u", "");

                txtOutput.setText(quay + "quay");
            } else if ((Q == 'q' != true) && (Vowel == 'u' != true)) {
                String Reg = Inp[N];
                Reg = Reg.replaceAll("" + Q, "");

                txtOutput.setText(Reg + Q + "ay");
            } else if (Inp[N] == " ") {
                txtOutput.setText("" + DNC + "");
            } else {
                txtOutput.setText("" + Inp + "");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PigLatin(); // Create a PigLatin frame
    } // main method
} // PigLatin class
```

Comment: WTH? Why all the empty lines?? What error? Which line is 24? Also, please format your code so that it's readable, meaning use regular indentation of 4 spaces for each block, not random crazy indentations as your code shows

Comment: *"I get an error in my code for line 56."*  Always copy/paste error and exception output! *"..._____ (this is for the error that comes up with too much code)"*  Posting the error would have helped with that, as well as being more useful.

Comment: You need to mark the place in your code where the error hapens and what is the error. We are not going to count 56 lines to guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

I noticed a few things:

1. Solving your Problem: I guess you also had a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

   This comes along with the condition in your for-loop. In your statement you iterate over the length of the String at the current index. Which is a bit like traversing a matrix on its main-diagonal. I guess you wanted to iterate over all elements in your array `Inp`

   So changing your statement to:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < Int.length; i++){
       //...
   }
   ```

   should do the job.
2. A quick note on your if-statement:
   The second `} else if (Inp[N] == " ") {` is unnecessary because you did already split your input String on `" "`. So there shouldn't be any `" "` left in the results.
3. Please also specify a `defaultCloseOperation` for your `JFrame` so that your program stops correctly.

There is probably some more stuff that could be improved.

Comment: Thank you :D and for number 2 i was trying to make sure that if the user just presses the reverse string button it wouldn't bug out but it doesn't seem to work